# get number of repetitions of the searched word in elastic index

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, count, laravel-scout

How can I get number of repetition of the searched word in elastic index? 
I have a `Index` with two `types` that I want to sort on one of my `types`,  and for sort my search result I want to write a script includes sort by a algorithm..

So, for writing my algorithm I need the repetition number, and type length.. i found out that I can get my index length by calling this `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_stats?pretty=true` , but I couldn't find how to get the repetition number!

Can I get the repetition number? If I can, can anyone tell me how? and show me an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for frequency of term in entire index?

Comment: @Nirmal thanks for your response, l don't know what is that? can you show me an example?

Comment: This might help - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html